Eliminar datos de sitio, caché o cookies con javascript
Tengo un sitio desarrollado con js. Quiero que cuando el usuario inicie sesion se eliminen los datos de la caché. Haciendo algo similar a ir a preferencias->privacidad y seguridad -> limpiar datos.
El sitio se visualiza en mozilla.
he probado utilizando caches y browser pero no funciona.
¡¡AYUDAA!!

A lo que yo tengo entendido no es posible hacerlo debido a restricciones de seguridad de los navegadores, debes de hacerlo manualmente siempre.

Porqué quieres que tu sitio borre la caché??

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

¿Por qué querrías que tu sitio automáticamente borre la caché (o datos, según tu ejemplo) de tu navegador?

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Puedes hacer varias cosas:

Limpiar la caché con la API Cache: limpiar las cachés específicas de tu sitio.

if ('caches' in window) {
  caches.keys().then((names) => {
    names.forEach((name) => {
      caches.delete(name);
    });
  });
}


Limpiar localStorage: El local storage se limpia con una sola linea de codigo.

localStorage.clear();


Limpiar sessionStorage: El sessionStorage se limpia con una sola linea de codigo.

sessionStorage.clear();

Yo lo simplificaria de la siguiente forma (es como lo tengo en mis proyectos):
function clearCacheAndStorage() {
  // Clear Cache
  if ('caches' in window) {
    caches.keys().then((names) => {
      names.forEach((name) => {
        caches.delete(name);
      });
    });
  }

  // Clear localStorage
  localStorage.clear();

  // Clear sessionStorage
  sessionStorage.clear();
}

// Triger Limpieza del sistema
document.getElementById('CleanRefresh').addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  //llamada al metodo de la limpieza
  clearCacheAndStorage();

  // Redirigir o actualizar la página según sea necesario
  window.location.reload();
});

